# Unable to read data from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

## CODE

```
final List<Shop> mShops = new ArrayList<>();
mRef.child("shops").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot noteSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Shop data = noteSnapshot.getValue(Shop.class);
            Log.e("log", data.getName()+" "+data.getUrl());
            Shops.add(data);
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
         Log.d("LOG", databaseError.getMessage());
     }
});
for (Shop shop : mShops) {
    Log.e("mShops", shop.getName()+" "+shop.getUrl());
}
```

## LOG

```
E/log: Levi's https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-87605.appspot.com/o/storefront27.jpg?alt=media&token=4ea27811-4e06-4bf5-8b96-44a583040088
E/log: Dunkin Donuts https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-87605.appspot.com/o/dunkin.jpg?alt=media&token=f63c6d5f-b074-47ae-a8ca-6f7974ddbd47
E/log: Pizza Parlor https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-87605.appspot.com/o/download.jpg?alt=media&token=1eb9a9bb-495d-416b-9a84-3699214149b9
E/log: Town Bakers https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-87605.appspot.com/o/download%20(1).jpg?alt=media&token=01b16918-272f-4a9f-9607-61f559d30360
```

The data is being read from the database within onDataChange but i am unable to store and read it from the mShops list.I would appreciate any help in find out the reason why this data isn't being stored in the list.

Comment: have you ruled out the possibility that you haven't called notifyDataSetChanged() with the adapter, assuming there is one with your list? The data seems to be stored in the list.

Comment: side note, not a good practice doing the for (Shop shop : mShops) { } where you have there , since the operation is async, your outter for each loop may or may not run exactly after the all the items are populated.

Comment: Call a method from the onDataChange after the for loop in which you are adding data to the mShops. In that method try to print using the mShops. That will work.

Comment: provide your firebase database schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, simply move the declaration of your `mShops` list inside the `onDataChange()` like this:

```
mRef.child("shops").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Shop> mShops = new ArrayList<>();

        for (DataSnapshot noteSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Shop data = noteSnapshot.getValue(Shop.class);
            Log.e("log", data.getName()+" "+data.getUrl());
            mShops.add(data);
         }

         for (Shop shop : mShops) {
             Log.e("mShops", shop.getName()+" "+shop.getUrl());
         }
     }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("LOG", databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Note, that with this code, your `ArrayList` does not need to be final. Remember, `onDataChange()` method has an asynchronous behavior which means that is called even before you are trying to add those objects of class `Shop` to the list.

Comment: Thank you again. I just got a chance to learn and clear my doubt about the 'final` keyword. +1

Answer (score 0):

**Edited after Alex's suggestions**

What you can do here is pass every data from `onDataChange()` to another method and access it from there or if you're just planning to print the data on log try shifting this line(without final)

```
List<Shop> mShops = new ArrayList<>();
```

inside this

```
mRef.child("shops").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {}
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. When you are using `final` keyword it doesn't mean that you cannot add elements to the list is means that the compiler makes sure that you can initialize a variable only once. With other words, you cannot reassign a new value to `mShops` object.

Comment: Thank you for the information. But I've gone through the same situation a lot of time where list would never add up a object if it is declared final.  So, can I add value to mShops? If yes, then is there a way to make it sure that the element is being added?